# SSRS Color formatting of particular string

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a requirement to display select statement on SSRS report (UI). I want to display select, from and where in Bold and blue color. Field name = "Query" and below is a record

```
 select field1, field2 from table1 where field1='test'
```

I tried both below font->expression of "Query" field, but it's not working.

```
 =Replace("SELECT",Fields!Query.Value," `<span style='color:red'>` " & Fields!Query.Value & "`</span>`")
 =Replace(Fields!Query.Value,"SELECT"," `<span style='color:red'>` " & Fields!Query.Value & "`</span>`")
```

Comment: You've replaced the word SELECT with the entire query string, only in red (assuming the HTML portion is correct - I've not checked). You need to replace "select" with "select" in red, then use the result of this to do your next replace and repeat until all three are done

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is as follows 
**note: my column is called `sql`, not `Query` as it is in yours**

Create a textbox (or edit your existing one)

Type `SELECT` then a `[space]`

Then right-click inside the text box to the right of what you just typed and choose `Create placeholder`

Set the `value` expression to be

```
=
MID(
    Fields!sql.Value,
    INSTR(Fields!sql.Value, "SELECT ", Compare:= Comparemethod.Text) + 7,
    INSTR(Fields!sql.Value, "FROM", Compare:= Comparemethod.Text) 
        - (INSTR(Fields!sql.Value, "SELECT ", Compare:= Comparemethod.Text) + 8)
    )
```

Now type a `[space]` and then 'FROM', add your next placeholder with the following expression.

```
=
MID(
    Fields!sql.Value,
    INSTR(Fields!sql.Value, "FROM ", Compare:= Comparemethod.Text) + 5,
    INSTR(Fields!sql.Value, "WHERE", Compare:= Comparemethod.Text) 
        - (INSTR(Fields!sql.Value, "FROM ", Compare:= Comparemethod.Text) + 6)
    )
```

finally type "WHERE " and the last placeholder, set the expression to...

```
=
MID(
    Fields!sql.Value,
    INSTR(Fields!sql.Value, "WHERE ", Compare:= Comparemethod.Text) + 6
    )
```

You can now double-click the static words and format as you wish. You could do the same with each expression to as all placeholders have their own font properties.

The final design looks like this...

[image]

And the final output looks like this.
[image]

Comment: But my output is one select statement. In this way, it will become to challenge to put expressions in between select & from & where. Any other way to handle pls?

Comment: What is Compare:= Comparemethod.Text? I'm getting an error. Is "sql" field name is compare?

Comment: The output IS one select statement, the contents are in a single textbox. Compare:= Compare.Text makes the InStr function be case insensitive. sql is the field in my dataset. I said at the start of my answer. You will need to swap that out for your `Query` field.

Comment: but select statement / where / table name may appears as many times in a select statement. How to handle?

Comment: Your question did not make this clear. You should refer to my original comment about doing the replace method

Comment: What should be myreplace line...? What is replace expression? Please help me out...